# Posicionar imagem à direita e ao top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Com esse código, consigo manter à direita a imagem:

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-right"><img src="~/Images/ache.jpg" /></a>
```

Porem essa imagem fica dentro de uma barra de menu. Eu tenho uma imagem e redimencionei de forma a ter a mesma altura da barra(Heigth). Bem, quando isso acontece, a imagem de posiciona abaixo do top da barra, ou seja, ela fica com uma parte para fora da barra(pra baixo). Procurei alguma outra outra classe que pudesse ser usada jundo com o posicionamento à direita para fixar ela no topo da barra, mas não consegui. Usei essa `navbar-fixed-top` mas não funcionou. Alguém tem uma idéia em como usar? Uso bootstrap 3, mvc 5.

Toda a minha master está aí

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Util.js")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right"><img src="~/Images/ache.jpg" /></a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Pedidos", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
                </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Laboratórios</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Testei várias coisas e não funcionou. Dei um float e também não. Veja a imagem da tela abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, não conseguir ver onde eu altero a tag . Veja o .css da navbars.less, acho ser esse o .css do layout.

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: @navbar-height; // Ensure a navbar always shows (e.g., without a .navbar-brand in collapsed mode)
  margin-bottom: @navbar-margin-bottom;
  border: 1px solid transparent;

  // Prevent floats from breaking the navbar
  &:extend(.clearfix all);

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    border-radius: @navbar-border-radius;
  }
}


// Navbar heading
//
// Groups `.navbar-brand` and `.navbar-toggle` into a single component for easy
// styling of responsive aspects.

.navbar-header {
  &:extend(.clearfix all);

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    float: left;
  }
}


// Navbar collapse (body)
//
// Group your navbar content into this for easy collapsing and expanding across
// various device sizes. By default, this content is collapsed when <768px, but
// will expand past that for a horizontal display.
//
// To start (on mobile devices) the navbar links, forms, and buttons are stacked
// vertically and include a `max-height` to overflow in case you have too much
// content for the user's viewport.

.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: @navbar-collapse-max-height;
  overflow-x: visible;
  padding-right: @navbar-padding-horizontal;
  padding-left:  @navbar-padding-horizontal;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  &:extend(.clearfix all);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  &.in {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;

    &.collapse {
      display: block !important;
      height: auto !important;
      padding-bottom: 0; // Override default setting
      overflow: visible !important;
    }

    &.in {
      overflow-y: visible;
    }

    // Undo the collapse side padding for navbars with containers to ensure
    // alignment of right-aligned contents.
    .navbar-fixed-top &,
    .navbar-static-top &,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom & {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
  }
}


// Both navbar header and collapse
//
// When a container is present, change the behavior of the header and collapse.

.container,
.container-fluid {
  > .navbar-header,
  > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -@navbar-padding-horizontal;
    margin-left:  -@navbar-padding-horizontal;

    @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-left:  0;
    }
  }
}


//
// Navbar alignment options
//
// Display the navbar across the entirety of the page or fixed it to the top or
// bottom of the page.

// Static top (unfixed, but 100% wide) navbar
.navbar-static-top {
  z-index: @zindex-navbar;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

// Fix the top/bottom navbars when screen real estate supports it
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: @zindex-navbar-fixed;

  // Undo the rounded corners
  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; // override .navbar defaults
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
}


// Brand/project name

.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  padding: @navbar-padding-vertical @navbar-padding-horizontal;
  font-size: @font-size-large;
  line-height: @line-height-computed;
  height: @navbar-height;

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    .navbar > .container &,
    .navbar > .container-fluid & {
      margin-left: -@navbar-padding-horizontal;
    }
  }
}


// Navbar toggle
//
// Custom button for toggling the `.navbar-collapse`, powered by the collapse
// JavaScript plugin.

.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: @navbar-padding-horizontal;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  .navbar-vertical-align(34px);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none; // Reset unusual Firefox-on-Android default style; see https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/214
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: @border-radius-base;

  // We remove the `outline` here, but later compensate by attaching `:hover`
  // styles to `:focus`.
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  // Bars
  .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
  }
  .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    display: none;
  }
}


// Navbar nav links
//
// Builds on top of the `.nav` components with its own modifier class to make
// the nav the full height of the horizontal nav (above 768px).

.navbar-nav {
  margin: (@navbar-padding-vertical / 2) -@navbar-padding-horizontal;

  > li > a {
    padding-top:    10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: @line-height-computed;
  }

  @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint-max) {
    // Dropdowns get custom display when collapsed
    .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: static;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      box-shadow: none;
      > li > a,
      .dropdown-header {
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
      }
      > li > a {
        line-height: @line-height-computed;
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
          background-image: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Uncollapse the nav
  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;

    > li {
      float: left;
      > a {
        padding-top:    @navbar-padding-vertical;
        padding-bottom: @navbar-padding-vertical;
      }
    }

    &.navbar-right:last-child {
      margin-right: -@navbar-padding-horizontal;
    }
  }
}


// Component alignment
//
// Repurpose the pull utilities as their own navbar utilities to avoid specificity
// issues with parents and chaining. Only do this when the navbar is uncollapsed
// though so that navbar contents properly stack and align in mobile.

@media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
  .navbar-left  { .pull-left(); }
  .navbar-right { .pull-right(); }
}


// Navbar form
//
// Extension of the `.form-inline` with some extra flavor for optimum display in
// our navbars.

.navbar-form {
  margin-left: -@navbar-padding-horizontal;
  margin-right: -@navbar-padding-horizontal;
  padding: 10px @navbar-padding-horizontal;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  @shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  .box-shadow(@shadow);

  // Mixin behavior for optimum display
  .form-inline();

  .form-group {
    @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint-max) {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }

  // Vertically center in expanded, horizontal navbar
  .navbar-vertical-align(@input-height-base);

  // Undo 100% width for pull classes
  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    .box-shadow(none);

    // Outdent the form if last child to line up with content down the page
    &.navbar-right:last-child {
      margin-right: -@navbar-padding-horizontal;
    }
  }
}


// Dropdown menus

// Menu position and menu carets
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  .border-top-radius(0);
}
// Menu position and menu caret support for dropups via extra dropup class
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  .border-bottom-radius(0);
}


// Buttons in navbars
//
// Vertically center a button within a navbar (when *not* in a form).

.navbar-btn {
  .navbar-vertical-align(@input-height-base);

  &.btn-sm {
    .navbar-vertical-align(@input-height-small);
  }
  &.btn-xs {
    .navbar-vertical-align(22);
  }
}


// Text in navbars
//
// Add a class to make any element properly align itself vertically within the navbars.

.navbar-text {
  .navbar-vertical-align(@line-height-computed);

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    float: left;
    margin-left: @navbar-padding-horizontal;
    margin-right: @navbar-padding-horizontal;

    // Outdent the form if last child to line up with content down the page
    &.navbar-right:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}

// Alternate navbars
// --------------------------------------------------

// Default navbar
.navbar-default {
  background-color: @navbar-default-bg;
  border-color: @navbar-default-border;

  .navbar-brand {
    color:@navbar-default-brand-color;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      color: @navbar-default-brand-hover-color;
      background-color: @navbar-default-brand-hover-bg;
    }
  }

  .navbar-text {
    color: @navbar-default-color;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    > li > a {
      color: @navbar-default-link-color;

      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @navbar-default-link-hover-color;
        background-color: @navbar-default-link-hover-bg;
      }
    }
    > .active > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @navbar-default-link-active-color;
        background-color: @navbar-default-link-active-bg;
      }
    }
    > .disabled > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-color;
        background-color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-bg;
      }
    }
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: @navbar-default-toggle-border-color;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: @navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg;
    }
    .icon-bar {
      background-color: @navbar-default-toggle-icon-bar-bg;
    }
  }

  .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-form {
    border-color: @navbar-default-border;
  }

  // Dropdown menu items
  .navbar-nav {
    // Remove background color from open dropdown
    > .open > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        background-color: @navbar-default-link-active-bg;
        color: @navbar-default-link-active-color;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint-max) {
      // Dropdowns get custom display when collapsed
      .open .dropdown-menu {
        > li > a {
          color: @navbar-default-link-color;
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            color: @navbar-default-link-hover-color;
            background-color: @navbar-default-link-hover-bg;
          }
        }
        > .active > a {
          &,
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            color: @navbar-default-link-active-color;
            background-color: @navbar-default-link-active-bg;
          }
        }
        > .disabled > a {
          &,
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-color;
            background-color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-bg;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


  // Links in navbars
  //
  // Add a class to ensure links outside the navbar nav are colored correctly.

  .navbar-link {
    color: @navbar-default-link-color;
    &:hover {
      color: @navbar-default-link-hover-color;
    }
  }

}

// Inverse navbar

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #c81f61;//@navbar-inverse-bg;
  border-color: #c81f61;//@navbar-inverse-border;

  .navbar-brand {
    color: @navbar-inverse-brand-color;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      color: @navbar-inverse-brand-hover-color;
      background-color: @navbar-inverse-brand-hover-bg;
    }
  }

  .navbar-text {
    color: @navbar-inverse-color;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    > li > a {
      color: @navbar-inverse-link-color;

      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @navbar-inverse-link-hover-color;
        background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-hover-bg;
      }
    }
    > .active > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-color;
        background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-bg;
      }
    }
    > .disabled > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        color: @navbar-inverse-link-disabled-color;
        background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-disabled-bg;
      }
    }
  }

  // Darken the responsive nav toggle
  .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: @navbar-inverse-toggle-border-color;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: @navbar-inverse-toggle-hover-bg;
    }
    .icon-bar {
      background-color: @navbar-inverse-toggle-icon-bar-bg;
    }
  }

  .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-form {
    border-color: darken(@navbar-inverse-bg, 7%);
  }

  // Dropdowns
  .navbar-nav {
    > .open > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-bg;
        color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-color;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint-max) {
      // Dropdowns get custom display
      .open .dropdown-menu {
        > .dropdown-header {
          border-color: @navbar-inverse-border;
        }
        .divider {
          background-color: @navbar-inverse-border;
        }
        > li > a {
          color: @navbar-inverse-link-color;
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            color: @navbar-inverse-link-hover-color;
            background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-hover-bg;
          }
        }
        > .active > a {
          &,
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-color;
            background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-bg;
          }
        }
        > .disabled > a {
          &,
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            color: @navbar-inverse-link-disabled-color;
            background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-disabled-bg;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .navbar-link {
    color: @navbar-inverse-link-color;
    &:hover {
      color: @navbar-inverse-link-hover-color;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Poste todo o conteúdo html desta parte da barra para saber como você montou a estrutura, assim fica mais fácil de entender o que está sendo interpretado pelo navegador e podemos lhe passar uma resposta mais efetiva

Comment: Sim, passe o CSS também

Comment: Fiz  a edição. O CSS é o bootstrap puro, sem customização de minha parte.

Comment: Postei a imagem da tela. O logo ACHE está mais para baixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho quase certeza que o bootstrap coloca padding automatico, tanto na imagem quanto no link.

```
img{
border:none;
padding:0;
margin:0
}
```

e verifique se as classe:
navbar-brand navbar-right

tbm estão com os padding e margin zerados.

A melhor forma de descobrir o motivo é inspecionar o elemento com o firebug ou [Brackets.io](http://brackets.io)

Comment: Fiz uma edição e postei o css. Estou com dificuldade para localizar o problema relatado por vocês.

Comment: Experimentou usar o firebug na imagem?

Answer (score 1):

Já verificou se o `<a>` e a `<img>` estão zerados?

```
a{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

img{
border:none;
padding:0;
margin:0
}
```

Em ultimo caso tente colocar o elemento pai da `<a>` com position:relative e coloque a `<a>` com position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Realmente era o brand. Essa é a linha.

```
.........
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;//@navbar-padding-vertical @navbar-padding-horizontal;-- 
  font-size: @font-size-large;
  line-height: @line-height-computed;
.............
```